# Scrapy: Linkextractor Rule not working

Tags: python, scrapy

I have tried 3 different variations of LinkExtractor, but its still ignoring the 'deny' rule and crawling sub-domains in all 3 variations.... I want to EXCLUDE the sub-domains from the crawl.

**Tried with 'allow' rule only. To only allow the main domain** i.e. example.edu.uk

```
rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'^example\.edu.uk(\/.*)?$',)))] // Not Working
```

**Tried with 'deny' rule only. To deny all sub-domains** i.e. sub.example.edu.uk

```
rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(deny=(r'(?<=\.)[a-z0-9-]*\.edu\.uk',)))] // Not Working
```

**Tried with both 'allow & deny' rule**

```
rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'^http:\/\/example\.edu\.uk(\/.*)?$'),deny=(r'(?<=\.)[a-z0-9-]*\.edu\.uk',)))] // Not Working
```

**Example:**

**Follow these links**

- example.edu.uk/fsdfs.htm
- example.edu.uk/nkln.htm
- example.edu.uk/vefr.htm
- example.edu.uk/opji.htm

**Discard sub-domain links**

- sub-domain.example.edu.uk/fsdfs.htm
- sub-domain.example.edu.uk/nkln.htm
- sub-domain.example.edu.uk/vefr.htm
- sub-domain.example.edu.uk/opji.htm

**Here is the complete code ...**

```
class NewsFields(Item):
    pagetype = Field()
    pagetitle = Field()
    pageurl = Field()
    pagedate = Field()
    pagedescription = Field()
    bodytext = Field()

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'profiles'
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.edu.uk/listing']
    allowed_domains = ['example.edu.uk']
    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'^https?://example.edu.uk/.*', ))), )
    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body, 'lxml')
        nf = NewsFields()
        ptype = soup.find_all(attrs={"name":"nkdpagetype"})
        ptitle = soup.find_all(attrs={"name":"nkdpagetitle"})
        pturl = soup.find_all(attrs={"name":"nkdpageurl"})
        ptdate = soup.find_all(attrs={"name":"nkdpagedate"})
        ptdesc = soup.find_all(attrs={"name":"nkdpagedescription"})
        for node in soup.find_all("div", id="main-content__wrapper"):
             ptbody = ''.join(node.find_all(text=True))
             ptbody = ' '.join(ptbody.split())
             nf['pagetype'] = ptype[0]['content'].encode('ascii', 'ignore')
             nf['pagetitle'] = ptitle[0]['content'].encode('ascii', 'ignore')
             nf['pageurl'] = pturl[0]['content'].encode('ascii', 'ignore')
             nf['pagedate'] = ptdate[0]['content'].encode('ascii', 'ignore')
             nf['pagedescription'] = ptdesc[0]['content'].encode('ascii', 'ignore')
             nf['bodytext'] = ptbody.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
             yield nf
            for url in hxs.xpath('//p/a/@href').extract():
             yield Request(response.urljoin(url), callback=self.parse)
```

Can someone please help ?
Thanks

Comment: Post some sample links also that you want to be processed and the ones that you don't want to be processed

Comment: Also please post when you say not working, what is that us happening? post logs if possible

Comment: Hi @TarunLalwani What is it that you don't understand in my question ? All links in the main domain must be crawled and all links under sub-domains must be discarded. Anyway, I have updated the question. See above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first 2 rules are wrong

```
rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'^example\.edu.uk(\/.*)?$',)))] // Not Working
rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(deny=(r'(?<=\.)[a-z0-9-]*\.edu\.uk',)))] // Not Working
```

The allow and deny are for absolute urls and not domain. The below should work for you

```
rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'^https?://example.edu.uk/.*', ))), )
```

**Edit-1**

First you should change below

```
allowed_domains = ['example.edu.uk']
```

to

```
allowed_domains = ['www.example.edu.uk']
```

Second your rules for extracting URL should be

```
rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'^https?://www.example.edu.uk/.*', ))), )
```

Third, in your below code

```
for url in hxs.xpath('//p/a/@href').extract():
         yield Request(response.urljoin(url), callback=self.parse)
```

Rules will not be applied. Your yields are subject to rules. Rule will insert new request automatically, but they will not prevent you from yielding other links which are not allowed by the rule config. But setting `allowed_domains` will be applicable to both rules and your yield

Comment: Thanks @TarunLalwani I tried your code, but its still crawling sub-domain pages. Looks like I need to explicitly deny sub-domain in the rule.

Comment: Post the complete scraper in your question

Comment: Hi @TarunLalwani please see above. Complete code added.

Comment: Thanks @TarunLalwani Just adding www to `allowed_domains = ['www.example.edu.uk']` worked. I deleted the Rules. And its working as expected, its not crawling sub-domains anymore ...